# @font-face not loading over https when using src: url(data:font)

Tags: css, truetype

How do you force the URL to use https when defining font styles in CSS via this method?

```
@font-face {
font-family: "font-name";
src: url(data:font/truetype;base64,AAEEEEAXX........);
font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using data:font/trueType, you are not loading any file. You can't set any protocol.

From MDN:

> Data URLs are treated as unique opaque origins by modern browsers,
>   rather than inheriting the origin of the settings object responsible
>   for the navigation.